# Добавить класс при клике другому div

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть несколько `select`-oв. Если мы на него кликаем добовляется `class="open"` нашему списку. Как это можно реализовать на Vue.js. С помощью JQ это получается реализовать:

```
methods: {
  toggleClass(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).children('.option_box').toggleClass('open');
}
```

}

а без него не выходит.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    isOpen: false
  },
  methods: {
   toggleClass(e) {
     this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}
.select {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.input_val {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.option_box {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}
.option_box.open {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="select"  @click="toggleClass">
    <div class="input_val">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ option_box: true, open: isOpen }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in 3">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="select"  @click="toggleClass">
    <div class="input_val">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ option_box: true, open: isOpen }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in 5">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="select"  @click="toggleClass">
    <div class="input_val">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ option_box: true, open: isOpen }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in 6">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` тут явно лишний. Первое что пришло в голову, не очень изящный способ, но работает

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    toggleClass(event) {
      event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}
.select {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.input_val {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.option_box {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}
.option_box.open {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="select"  @click="toggleClass">
    <div class="input_val">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ option_box: true }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in 3">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="select"  @click="toggleClass">
    <div class="input_val">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ option_box: true }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in 5">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="select"  @click="toggleClass">
    <div class="input_val">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ option_box: true }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in 6">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тут идет плохая привязка через соседа и повтор похожего хтмл.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Согласен, очень легко поломать

Answer (score 1):

Не советую так повторяться в хтмл, можно использовать `v-for` чтобы отображать похожие элементы, в моем варианте этот подход и задействован.

Также обратите что data [должно быть функцией](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-data-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    options: [
      {
        length: 3,
        isOpen: false
      },
            {
        length: 5,
        isOpen: false
      },
      {
        length: 6,
        isOpen: false
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
   toggleClass (option) {
      console.log(option)
     option.isOpen = !option.isOpen
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}
.select {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.input_val {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.option_box {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}
.option_box.open {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div 
    v-for="(option, i) in options" 
    :key="i"
    class="select"
  >
    <div class="input_val" @click="toggleClass(option)">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ option_box: true, open: option.isOpen }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in option.length">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Передавать индекс параметром в функцию

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    openData: [{isOpen:false}, {isOpen:false}, {isOpen:false}],
  },
  methods: {
    toggleClass(i) {
      this.openData[i].isOpen = !this.openData[i].isOpen;
    },
    isOpen(i) {
      return this.openData[i].isOpen;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}
.select {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.input_val {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.option_box {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}
.option_box.open {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.open {
   background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="select"  @click="toggleClass(0)">
    <div class="input_val">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ 'option_box': true, 'open': isOpen(0) }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in 3">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="select"  @click="toggleClass(1)">
    <div class="input_val">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ 'option_box': true, 'open': isOpen(1) }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in 5">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="select"  @click="toggleClass(2)">
    <div class="input_val">
      <input class="input" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ 'option_box': true, 'open': isOpen(2) }">
      <li class="option" v-for="n in 6">{{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```